# dependency injection of 3rd party singleton class with Spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, validation

I'm using apache commons validator in few classes in my project, and I want to inject the singleton to my Class.

to use the validator you need to get the instance of the singleton like this:

```
  // Get an EmailValidator
  EmailValidator validator = EmailValidator.getInstance();
```

My question is how exactly could I inject the EmailValidator class to my project with annotations. I didn't find any reference about these sort of things...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare the EmailValidator bean in the Spring XML and tell Spring to use a static factory method to instantiate it. See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-class-static-factory-method.

Or create a Spring bean implementing `FactoryBean<EmailValidator>`. See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-factorybean.